# What is the algebraic interpretation of a contracted product?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, representation-theory, sheaf-theory

Suppose you have a linear reductive group $G$ acting on an algebraic variety $X$. Let $P\leq G$ be an algebraic subgroup and let $Y \subseteq X$ be a closed subvariety, invariant under $P$. Then a number of texts define the construction of the so called "contracted" or "twisted" product give by $G \times^P Y := G \times Y /\sim \quad \quad$ where $(gp, y) \sim (g, py)$ for all $p \in P$.

My question is this: What is the algebraic interpretation of this geometric space and how should I be thinking about this scheme? In the case that it is affine, is there simple description of its coordinate ring?

Also does anyone have any references for a good exposition of these concepts? If there were a more categorical description of this object that would also be amazing (i.e. a definition given by diagrams etc.).

Thanks! Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Looks a lot like a tensor product to me, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154795/90543) for a categorical description of this construction. Maybe there's something subtle going on in the algebro-geometric context, but assuming this quotient gives the coequalizer of the two maps $G\times P \times Y \to G\times Y$, then the answer applies.

Comment: This is often called the 'associated bundle' construction, when $Y$ is a fibre bundle.